# Turn the screensaver off using xdg-screensaver

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver, xdg

I am facing problem turning off screensaver with bash script in Ubuntu 22.04. I am running a script something like that:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
xdg-screensaver lock
sleep 5m
xdg-screensaver reset
```

It should lock immediately, wait for five minutes and then prompt to unlock, but it is not working. Is there any way to wake up screen and prompt to unlock? Thank you!

Comment: Screensaver in Gnome is running on TTY1, and the user session on TTY2, whereas formerly, all was running on TTY7. That could be why this approach currently does not anymore work.